# I can't figure out why my code for using the local timezone for the phone doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone, nsdate

I am writing an app that uses UINotifications and I have the code functioning for the notifications but can't get the correct time zone.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

// Get the current date
NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];
// Break the date up into components
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit)
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];
```

I am pretty sure I am getting it correctly in the NSDateComponents above

```
// Set up the fire time
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
```

Here is where I am pretty sure the timezone should be set for the current phone location

```
[dateComps setTimeZone:[dateComponents timeZone]];

[dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",itemDate]);
```

I try and dump the itemDate to the Log file and what I get looks like GMT

```
2013-11-07 00:24:14.559 IMOB[796:60b] 2013-11-07 08:23:56 +0000
```

and as you can see in the timestamp at the beginning of the log file line it shows that is correctly 12:24 in the morning yet the output reads 08:23

what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

`NSDate` objects are always UTC. Use `NSDateFormatter` to log the value according to your locale.

`[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:]` is very handy.